# Can set the value of the previous query

Tags: t-sql

how to `SET` return value to new `query` ?

query like :

```
DECLARE @count;   

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE x = 1;

SET @count = //result_last_query

SELECT * FROM b WHERE z = @count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as :

```
 SELECT *  FROM b
     where z=(select count(*) FROM a FROM a WHERE x = 1;)}
```

You dont even require any variable declaration

Answer (score 1):

thanks good solution

I modified the code of answers

```
SELECT  *
FROM    B
WHERE   id IN (
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM A
                WHERE x = 1
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the resultset of the select query and want to access the row count in next statement **you could use** `@@rowcount`

Example Usage:

```
Select top 10 * from SomeTable
SELECT @@rowcount
```

First query in above script will return 10 rows and the second query will return `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. You can set in query as the below:

```
DECLARE @count INT   

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE x = 1

SELECT * FROM b WHERE z = @count
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to put the variable in the query itself, in order to set the variable's value with the row count.

Then you can use the variable's value in the next query.

```
DECLARE @count;   

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE x = 1;

SELECT * FROM b WHERE z = @count;
```

But, be careful that the variable will only be visible during execution so you need to execute ***this entire script*** all at once in order for the `@count` variable to work for the last query.